# Help me make sense of this guitar amp relay circuit

Tags: led, amplifier, diodes, ac-dc, vacuum-tube

Here is a channel-switching relay from a guitar amplifier. It is supplied with 6.3 V AC. Closing the switch (near center) operates the relay. It's on a schematic that's taped to my wall, and I started wondering about it.

- How is the relay being signaled, what is it "listening for", and how does this circuit achieve this?
- Why is the LED placed between two resistors of equal value?

[image: Channel-switching relay]

Comment: This circuit is a bit weird. What's the phono jack for?

Comment: Do you have a photo of the LED and two resistors?  I'm wondering if the second resistor saves a wire link or some similar purpose.

Comment: Could you give the model of the amplifier, or is it custom?

Comment: @Hearth The phono jack is for a footswitch, which serves the same purpose (it shorts the circuit) as the switch on the amp itself.

Answer (score 5):

It's not 'listening for a signal'.

The diode and 470\$\mu\$F capacitor rectify and filter the 6.3 V AC voltage providing a DC supply to power the relay. Closing the switch simply completes the circuit.

The jack is for a remote switch, it's in parallel with the channel switch, so connecting another switch through the jack will duplicate the switching function.

The LED is on when the switch is off, getting it's power through the relay coil. When the switch (or remote switch) is closed it causes a short across the LED turning it off. Why they have a resistor on either side of it, who knows. They could have just as easily used one resistor twice the value of each of them (680\$\Omega\$ is a common value that would work) or two on one side and none on the other, makes no difference to how it works.

Comment: The two resistor may duplicate as extra leads for the LED to allow mounting it without other wires.

Comment: @Justme Yeah, that could be it.

Comment: or they are using 330 ohm elsewhere on the BOM and are reducing parts count.